# Create a pager for views output

Tags: views

How can I make a pager for views output to limit them at 10 entries?

```
$view = views_get_view('myview', 'default');
$view->override_path = $_GET['q'];
$view_output = $view->execute_display('page_1', array($tid));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Drupal Views module provides this functionality. You don't need to write the code for that.
See the image below[image]
Here you can set item to display as want. It has many more options